# OpenCL inconsistent results from kernel

Tags: parallel-processing, opencl, gpu

When I try this I get the wrong result at 'output' even though I am copying the values of 'cum' array to output.

But if I rename the 'cum' array mentioned earlier in the code. I get the correct value of array. Therefore I am unable to reuse the result values.

The device has 8 cores with no shared memory.

Any and all comments/suggestions appreciated.

```
kernel void histogram(global unsigned int *input,
                             global unsigned int *output,
                             global unsigned int *frequency,
                             global unsigned int *cum,
                             unsigned int N) 
{
    int pid = get_global_id(0);

    //cumulative sum
    for(int i=0; i < 16; i++)
    {               
        cum[(i*16)+(2*pid)+1] = frequency[(i*16)+(2*pid)] + frequency[(i*16)+(2*pid)+1];
    }
    barrier(CLK_GLOBAL_MEM_FENCE);

    for(int i=0; i < 32; i++)
    {               
        output[(i*8)+pid] = cum[(i*8)+pid]; 
    }

    barrier(CLK_GLOBAL_MEM_FENCE);
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "rename"?

Comment: By rename I mean `output[(i*16)+(2*pid)+1] = frequency[(i*16)+(2*pid)] + frequency[(i*16)+(2*pid)+1];`, gives proper output.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you understand parallel prefix sums. In particular I don't see a downsweep step of the total sum or parts:

[Parallel Prefix Sum (Scan) with CUDA](https://developer.nvidia.com/gpugems/GPUGems3/gpugems3_ch39.html)

I'd look in the TI's Keystone II SDK you're using in [OpenCL device memory read/write issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29887169/opencl-device-memory-read-write-issue)  to see if they have any scan or parallel prefix sum implementations or built in functions.

Comment: I had inititally written code for that. using complete upsweep and downsweep. But the values output array were random. So I thought I would do it step by step. The above code is step 1 of upsweep operation.
The output data which I am getting from my code is inconsistent. The results at output[0-4] (and multiples of (0-4) *8cores) are mostly right but output[5-7] (multiples of (5-7) *8cores) are inconsistent (appear as 0 most of the time).

Comment: what is the size of your work group and range of pid? I just want to make sure cum is computing (setting) what you think it is computing.

Comment: I just have 8 work items and pid goes from 0 to 7. Each with no shared memory.

Comment: are you zeroing out any of output/cum before hand?  It might  help you discover something more if you do that.  Also, don't use get_global_id, use get_local_id for this type of operation.

Comment: I'd also recommend you try your code "ported" to matlab/octave/numpy so you can see what you're doing more interactively - it may help you debug non-opencl related problems.

Comment: oh and I keep forgetting to ask but show some example input and outputs.